# list the users who belongs a particular group

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I want to print the users whose group is "devops" from the given local variables. I actually tried with the `devops_users = { for k, v in local.user: keys(local.users) => if local.user[*].group == "devops" }` and it errored out  " Error: Invalid 'for' expression"

Can anyone suggest to me the correct expression?

```
locals { 
    users = {
        tom = {
            city = "SFO"
            email = "abc@gmail.com"
            group = "Engg"
        },
        alex = {
            city = "LAX"
            email = "alex@gmail.com"
            group = "Devops"
        },
        vald = {
            city = "NYC"
            email = "vald@gmail.com"
            group = "Engg"
        },  
        leena = {
            city = "OHO"
            email = "leena@gmail.com"
            group = "Devops"
        },
        saami = {
            city = "ORD"
            email = "saami@gmail.com"
            group = "Devops"
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were making it a bit complex.

```
output "devops_users" {
  value = { for k, v in local.users : k => v if v.group == "Devops" }
}
```

Giving:

```
  + devops_users = {
      + alex  = {
          + city  = "LAX"
          + email = "alex@gmail.com"
          + group = "Devops"
        }
      + leena = {
          + city  = "OHO"
          + email = "leena@gmail.com"
          + group = "Devops"
        }
      + saami = {
          + city  = "ORD"
          + email = "saami@gmail.com"
          + group = "Devops"
        }
    }
```

Or if you only want the name:

```
output "devops_users_list" {
  value = [for k, v in local.users : k if v.group == "Devops"]
}
```

Giving:

```
  + devops_users_list = [
      + "alex",
      + "leena",
      + "saami",
    ]
```

Also, you use `local.user` which isn't defined and match `"devops"` rather than `"Devops"` as shown in the data set.